# Split a list into sublists, when size of sublist relies on data values (Seed and extend)

Tags: python

I have a list where headers begin with a `"Header"` string, and the corresponding
data associated with the header contiguously follows it in the list, ending with the next `"Header"` prefixed element:

```
data = ["Header: 1",
        "Some info 1",
        "Some info 2",
        "Some info 3",
        "Header: 2",
        "Some info 4",
        "Header: 3",
        "Some info 5",
        "Some info 6",
        ]
len(data) # returns 9
```

I would like to split the list at the header intervals, to create a list of header-data elements - it's the classic seed and extend. So the end goal is:

```
entries = [ ["Header: 1",
        "Some info 1",
        "Some info 2",
        "Some info 3"],
        ["Header: 2",
        "Some info 4"],
        ["Header: 3",
        "Some info 5",
        "Some info 6"]
        ]
 len(data) # returns 3
```

The number of data elements associated with each header is variable. 
Because each header begins with `"Header"` I can use this to determine
the intervals. 
I can use loops to solve:

```
entries = []
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    if "Header" in data[i]:
        entry = []
        entry.append(data[i])
        i = i + 1
        while("Header" not in data[i]):
            entry.append(data[i])
            i = i + 1
            if i == len(data):
                break
        entries.append(entry)
```

However, I wonder is there is a one liner (or something close) that can do this?
Perhaps a list comprehension approach. I'm not familiar with python libraries, but a solution from a standard library would also be fine.

Comment: So it starts with every `Header`?

Comment: Yes. The header elements of data always begin with the prefix `"Header"`.

Comment: And you know for sure the list starts with a header? If not what should happen?

Comment: I know that it will start with header, yes. I designed the output. Flexibility in this is not required ,but it would of course be a welcome accommodation. The more I learn of Python the better ;)

Comment: I do not understand what you gain from trying to write it in one line. As far as I understand you already have working code. Just put that code into a function which takes the data as argument and returns the new list and you basically have a one-liner.

Comment: @Share: well it can be a bit more elegant such that it is more clear what it does and less error prone.

Comment: Of course @Share, but it would be nice to know a more elegant solution. I'm trying to understand different approaches, like list comprehension etc. It's not ideal to write such a for-loop every time, also what if, onetime I forget the edge case where I over extend the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `itertools.groupby`, and group by "not starting with `Header`". Force list iteration on elements:

```
l = [list(x) for a,x in itertools.groupby(data,lambda x : not x.startswith("Header"))]
```

now `l` is `[['Header: 1'], ['Some info 1', 'Some info 2', 'Some info 3'], ['Header: 2'], ['Some info 4'], ['Header: 3'], ['Some info 5', 'Some info 6']]`

Then group the items 2 by 2:

```
result = [l[i]+l[i+1] for i in range(0,len(l),2)]
```

result:

```
[['Header: 1', 'Some info 1', 'Some info 2', 'Some info 3'], ['Header: 2', 'Some info 4'], ['Header: 3', 'Some info 5', 'Some info 6']]
```

Note: does not work if there are empty info blocks

Comment: Doh!  You beat me to the punch on using groupby.

Comment: Very nice. This is what I am looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me a more elegant way to do this is:

```
entries = []
entry = None
for element in data:
    if element.startswith('Header'): #or 'Header' in element if it can be everywhere
        entry = []
        entries.append(entry)
    entry.append(element)
```

Here you thus iterate over the `element`s in the `data`. You check if `"Header"` is in that `element`, we found a new "record", we construct an `entry` list with no elements (as the initial record) and add that `entry` to the `entries`. In any case we add the `element` to the current `entry` record.

Running this gives:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> data = ["Header: 1", \
...         "Some info 1", \
...         "Some info 2", \
...         "Some info 3",\
...         "Header: 2",\
...         "Some info 4",\
...         "Header: 3", \
...         "Some info 5",\
...         "Some info 6",\
...         ]
>>> 
>>> entries = []
>>> entry = None
>>> for element in data:
...     if "Header" in element:
...         entry = []
...         entries.append(entry)
...     entry.append(element)
... 
>>> entries
[['Header: 1', 'Some info 1', 'Some info 2', 'Some info 3'], ['Header: 2', 'Some info 4'], ['Header: 3', 'Some info 5', 'Some info 6']]
```

or in Python2:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> data = ["Header: 1", \
...         "Some info 1", \
...         "Some info 2", \
...         "Some info 3",\
...         "Header: 2",\
...         "Some info 4",\
...         "Header: 3", \
...         "Some info 5",\
...         "Some info 6",\
...         ]
>>> 
>>> entries = []
>>> entry = None
>>> for element in data:
...     if "Header" in element:
...         entry = []
...         entries.append(entry)
...     entry.append(element)
... 
>>> entries
[['Header: 1', 'Some info 1', 'Some info 2', 'Some info 3'], ['Header: 2', 'Some info 4'], ['Header: 3', 'Some info 5', 'Some info 6']]
```

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak: no this should normally work with python2 as well. Give me a minute.

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak: tested in `python2`, gives same result.

Comment: So, I did not know that an element of a list is aliased by the list index. Like, in this case, in the first loop, you can access `entries[0]` by `entries[0]` or by `entry`

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak: a list is *iterable* which means that you can use a `for` loop over it, and it *emits* the elements of the list. The same holds for `sets` and the **keys** of dictionaries by the way.

Comment: So if I have `alist = []` and `anotherlist = []`, then `anotherlist.append(alist)` and then `alist.append("100")`,  `anotherlist[0]` has the value `["100"]` and `alist[0]` has the value `"100"`.

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak: indeed, that is because Python works with references: you do not make copies of the list you append, you copy the reference. References are a very powerful (but a bit dangerous) concept in programming.

Comment: Right, I new python used references although, I would have imagined in this case it would have copied the list; it seems pretty dangerous in this sense, as you say.

Comment: I suppose, does python have some user definable scoping? So we could scope out `entry`, that way it will not exist outside the for loop. Like in C++ we could wrap the whole thing, including `entry` in curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

The following code explodes your list in sublists, then merges the sublists as you wanted them.

```
from itertools import groupby

splode = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x.startswith('Header'))]
merged = [h+i for h,i in zip(splode[::2],splode[1::2])]

> merged   # output is:
#[['Header: 1', 'Some info 1', 'Some info 2', 'Some info 3'],
# ['Header: 2', 'Some info 4'],
# ['Header: 3', 'Some info 5', 'Some info 6']]
```

Comment: Perhaps a tiny detail: the test of the OP is `in`, not `.startswith(` perhaps `TheHeader` is valid as well...

Comment: Perhaps.  But the very first line of his question indicates it begins with "Header".